# Add Value if Same Key from Object

Tags: javascript, object, key, key-value

```
var obj = {
bob : 14
jan : 2
}
```

If i add to this object, such as obj.bob = "12",
is there a way to add this to make bob : 26 instead of replacing it with bob: 12?
Thank you.

Comment: Increment current value .. `obj.bob += 12`

Comment: `obj.bob = obj.bob ? obj.bob + 12 : + 12`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, you use this way.

```
var obj = {
bob : 14,
jan : 2
}

obj.bob += 12;

console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 5):

You could use an ES6 feature, [`Proxy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy)

> The `Proxy` object is used to define custom behavior for fundamental operations (e.g. property lookup, assignment, enumeration, function invocation, etc).

```js
var obj = { bob: 14, jan: 2 },
    p = new Proxy(obj, {
        set: function(target, prop, value) {
            target[prop] = (target[prop] || 0) + value;
        }
    });
   
p.bob = 10;
console.log(p.bob); // 24
p.jane = 42;
console.log(p.jane); // 42
```

Comment: I should read more carefully, this is exactly what the OP wants xD

Comment: This can be done without proxies using setters and getters.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var obj = {
  bob : 14,
  jan : 2
}

obj.bob += 12;
console.log(obj.bob)
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple, and almost certainly correct, answer is to use the [addition assignment `+=` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators#Addition_assignment), which adds the right operand to the left operand.

```
obj.bob += 12; //obj.bob is now 26
```

You *may* want to have a system where setting a property with the [assignment operator `=`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators#Assignment_2) actually adds the value to the property's existing value. This seems confusing and unlikely to be helpful, but it is technically possible using [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty):

```
let _bob = 14;
Object.defineProperty(obj, 'bob', {
    set(newValue) {
        _bob += Number(newValue);
    },
    get() {
        return _bob;
    }
});

obj.bob = 12;
console.log(obj.bob); // logs '26'
```

I can't believe this is ever likely to be desired behaviour, however.

Comment: what do you do with a new property?

Comment: @NinaScholz An initial value is specified in the object literal in the question. This mirrors that.